# Spark RDD: AggregateByKey throws Task not serializable and I can't see non serializable objects

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, serialization, rdd

I have some code like this:

```
object Helpers {
   val getPercentVariationInterval = ( 
                                       prevStartClose: Double,
                                       prevEndClose: Double,
                                       prevStartDate: Date,
                                       prevEndDate: Date,
                                       newClose: Double,
                                       newDate: Date
                                      ) => 
                                      { 
                                       return something as 
                                       (Double, Double, Date, Date)
                                      }

   val seqOp = (
                 acc: (Double, Double, Date, Date, Double, Double, Long, Int), values: (Double, Double, Double, Double, Long, Int, Date)
               ) => 
               { 
                  getPercentVariationInterval()
                  return something as (Double, Double, Date, Date, Double, Double, Long, Int)
               }

   val compOP = (
                 acc1: (Double, Double, Date, Date, Double, Double, Long, Int), acc2: (Double, Double, Date, Date, Double, Double, Long, Int)
                ) => 
                {
                  getPercentVariationInterval()
                  return something as (Double, Double, Date, Date, Double, Double, Long, Int)
                }
}

   object JobOne extends Serializable {
      val run = () => {
      val rdd = ...
      val zeroVal = some value
//the RDD looks like RDD[(String, (Double, Double, Double, Double, Long, Int, Date))] but warns me about an implicit conversion, I don't know if that's relevant
      val result = rdd.aggregateByKey(zeroVal)(seqOP,compOP)
      }


 }
    object App{
   def  main(args: Array[String]) {
      JobOne.run()
   }
}
```

The error is this one:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2379)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$combineByKeyWithClassTag$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.combineByKeyWithClassTag(PairRDDFunctions.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$aggregateByKey$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.aggregateByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$aggregateByKey$5(PairRDDFunctions.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.aggregateByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:197)
    at big_data.job_one.JobOne$.$anonfun$run$1(App.scala:101)
    at big_data.job_one.App$.main(App.scala:116)
    at big_data.job_one.App.main(App.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.runtime.LazyRef
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: scala.runtime.LazyRef, value: LazyRef thunk)
    - element of array (index: 2)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 3)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function0.apply:()Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$aggregateByKey$2:([BLscala/reflect/ClassTag;Lscala/runtime/LazyRef;)Ljava/lang/Object;, instantiatedMethodType=()Ljava/lang/Object;, numCaptured=3])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$Lambda$832/956429999, org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$Lambda$832/956429999@150ede8b)
    - element of array (index: 1)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 2)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$aggregateByKey$3:(Lscala/Function2;Lscala/Function0;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, instantiatedMethodType=(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, numCaptured=2])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$Lambda$833/925152318, org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$Lambda$833/925152318@4b3fe06e)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
    ... 21 more
```

I don't understand what part of this is not serializable, trying to run seqOP and compOP inside JobOne by just calling them works (ex println(seqOP(something,something))), the problem arises if I pass the function inside aggregateByKey. 
I've already read several answers but nothing seems to help, either extending Serializable or turning def into functions.

I've tried putting the three functions in an object on their own, I've tried just slapping them as anonymous functions inside aggregateByKey, I've tried changing the arguments and return type to something more simple. Nothing works.

This is the whole code if needed, please this is driving me nuts: 
https://scalafiddle.io/sf/kh5zcN4/0

Edit: sorry I deleted the original question by mistake, it's 3am and I've been trying to understand this for hours.

Sample data as requested: https://pastebin.com/NDYFX8pJ

Comment: Can you add sample csv data which you have used in scalafiddle

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.com/NDYFX8pJ

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly was wrong, but it's Eclipse's fault somehow.
Using IntelliJ gave me no such problems.